# Is a dictionary ever used with the DEFLATE compression?

Tags: zlib

The [ZLIB format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1950#page-9) allows for the deflate algorithm to be primed with a preset dictionary. Is this feature used anywhere? Are there file formats or network protocols, etc. that make use of that feature?

Comment: I realized that I'm not aware of any uses of the ZLIB format, other than in PNG, so I changed the title to reflect the use of a dictionary with DEFLATE in general. Although, I'd be interested in seeing ZLIB with FDICT=1 used somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Here is [one example](https://blog.cloudflare.com/improving-compression-with-preset-deflate-dictionary) of a successful experiment with zlib dictionaries using on HTML pages, though it does not indicate if that has been put into practice.

Comment: The article talks about passing a dictionary to DEFLATE, but the Google SDCH actually uses the dictionary with VCDIFF. The output of that is compressed into a regular GZIP.